# Unknown host excpetion with jwk-set-uri (oauth2) in Springboot application

Tags: spring-boot, kubernetes, spring-security, spring-oauth2, spring-cloud-kubernetes

I have a spring boot application and I have a oauth2 client registration for security. 
I have this perfectly working when I run locally. I am able to generate token through my oauth2 provider and when I call the API with this token in Localhost, it works as expected.

But, when I deploy in Kubernetes cluster (with ingress with TLS)and call this API, it doesnt work. I always get error "Couldnot obtain the keys"  "Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: myidentityprovider.com: Temporary failure in name resolution". You can find the stack trace below.

> *Note: just replaced the original url to myidentityprovider.com*

what could be the problem? am I missing something?

```
    500 Server Error for HTTP GET "/testing"

    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not obtain the keys
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.NimbusReactiveJwtDecoder$JwkSetUriReactiveJwtDecoderBuilder.lambda$null$1(NimbusReactiveJwtDecoder.java:331) ~[spring-security-oauth2-jose-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    Suppressed: reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblyException: 
Error has been observed at the following site(s):
    |_ checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.web.server.authentication.AuthenticationWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    |_ checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.web.server.context.ReactorContextWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    |_ checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.web.server.csrf.CsrfWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    |_ checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.web.cors.reactive.CorsWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    |_ checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.web.server.header.HttpHeaderWriterWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    |_ checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.config.web.server.ServerHttpSecurity$ServerWebExchangeReactorContextWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    |_ checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.web.server.WebFilterChainProxy [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    |_ checkpoint ⇢ HTTP GET "/testing" [ExceptionHandlingWebHandler]
Stack trace:
        at org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.NimbusReactiveJwtDecoder$JwkSetUriReactiveJwtDecoderBuilder.lambda$null$1(NimbusReactiveJwtDecoder.java:331) ~[spring-security-oauth2-jose-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.2.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.lambda$onErrorMap$30(Mono.java:3275) ~[reactor-core-3.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:3.3.3.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnErrorResume$ResumeSubscriber.onError(FluxOnErrorResume.java:88) ~[reactor-core-3.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:3.3.3.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MultiSubscriptionSubscriber.onError(Operators.java:1944) ~[reactor-core-3.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:3.3.3.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onError(MonoFlatMap.java:165) ~[reactor-core-3.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:3.3.3.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MultiSubscriptionSubscriber.onError(Operators.java:1944) ~[reactor-core-3.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:3.3.3.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoSubscriber.onError(Operators.java:1752) ~[reactor-core-3.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:3.3.3.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoCacheTime$CoordinatorSubscriber.signalCached(MonoCacheTime.java:323) ~[reactor-core-3.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:3.3.3.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoCacheTime$CoordinatorSubscriber.onError(MonoCacheTime.java:346) ~[reactor-core-3.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:3.3.3.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeekFuseable$PeekFuseableSubscriber.onError(FluxPeekFuseable.java:227) ~[reactor-core-3.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:3.3.3.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onError(FluxMapFuseable.java:134) ~[reactor-core-3.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:3.3.3.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onError(MonoFlatMap.java:165) ~[reactor-core-3.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:3.3.3.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MultiSubscriptionSubscriber.onError(Operators.java:1944) ~[reactor-core-3.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:3.3.3.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onError(FluxMap.java:126) ~[reactor-core-3.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:3.3.3.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeek$PeekSubscriber.onError(FluxPeek.java:214) ~[reactor-core-3.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:3.3.3.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeek$PeekSubscriber.onError(FluxPeek.java:214) ~[reactor-core-3.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:3.3.3.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoNext$NextSubscriber.onError(MonoNext.java:87) ~[reactor-core-3.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:3.3.3.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMapMany$FlatMapManyMain.onError(MonoFlatMapMany.java:197) ~[reactor-core-3.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:3.3.3.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxRetryPredicate$RetryPredicateSubscriber.onError(FluxRetryPredicate.java:101) ~[reactor-core-3.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:3.3.3.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoCreate$DefaultMonoSink.error(MonoCreate.java:183) ~[reactor-core-3.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:3.3.3.RELEASE]
        at reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClientConnect$MonoHttpConnect$TcpClientSubscriber.onError(HttpClientConnect.java:346) ~[reactor-netty-0.9.5.RELEASE.jar!/:0.9.5.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoCreate$DefaultMonoSink.error(MonoCreate.java:183) ~[reactor-core-3.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:3.3.3.RELEASE]
        at reactor.netty.resources.PooledConnectionProvider$DisposableAcquire.onError(PooledConnectionProvider.java:468) ~[reactor-netty-0.9.5.RELEASE.jar!/:0.9.5.RELEASE]
        at reactor.netty.internal.shaded.reactor.pool.AbstractPool$Borrower.fail(AbstractPool.java:381) ~[reactor-netty-0.9.5.RELEASE.jar!/:0.9.5.RELEASE]
        at reactor.netty.internal.shaded.reactor.pool.SimplePool.lambda$drainLoop$7(SimplePool.java:206) ~[reactor-netty-0.9.5.RELEASE.jar!/:0.9.5.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.LambdaMonoSubscriber.doError(LambdaMonoSubscriber.java:152) ~[reactor-core-3.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:3.3.3.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.LambdaMonoSubscriber.onError(LambdaMonoSubscriber.java:147) ~[reactor-core-3.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:3.3.3.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoCreate$DefaultMonoSink.error(MonoCreate.java:183) ~[reactor-core-3.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:3.3.3.RELEASE]
        at reactor.netty.resources.PooledConnectionProvider$PooledConnectionAllocator$PooledConnectionInitializer.operationComplete(PooledConnectionProvider.java:282) ~[reactor-netty-0.9.5.RELEASE.jar!/:0.9.5.RELEASE]
        at reactor.netty.resources.PooledConnectionProvider$PooledConnectionAllocator$PooledConnectionInitializer.operationComplete(PooledConnectionProvider.java:232) ~[reactor-netty-0.9.5.RELEASE.jar!/:0.9.5.RELEASE]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListener0(DefaultPromise.java:577) ~[netty-common-4.1.45.Final.jar!/:4.1.45.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListenersNow(DefaultPromise.java:551) ~[netty-common-4.1.45.Final.jar!/:4.1.45.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListeners(DefaultPromise.java:490) ~[netty-common-4.1.45.Final.jar!/:4.1.45.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.setValue0(DefaultPromise.java:615) ~[netty-common-4.1.45.Final.jar!/:4.1.45.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.setFailure0(DefaultPromise.java:608) ~[netty-common-4.1.45.Final.jar!/:4.1.45.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.setFailure(DefaultPromise.java:109) ~[netty-common-4.1.45.Final.jar!/:4.1.45.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPromise.setFailure(DefaultChannelPromise.java:89) ~[netty-transport-4.1.45.Final.jar!/:4.1.45.Final]
        at io.netty.bootstrap.Bootstrap.doResolveAndConnect0(Bootstrap.java:208) ~[netty-transport-4.1.45.Final.jar!/:4.1.45.Final]
        at io.netty.bootstrap.Bootstrap.access$000(Bootstrap.java:46) ~[netty-transport-4.1.45.Final.jar!/:4.1.45.Final]
        at io.netty.bootstrap.Bootstrap$1.operationComplete(Bootstrap.java:180) ~[netty-transport-4.1.45.Final.jar!/:4.1.45.Final]
        at io.netty.bootstrap.Bootstrap$1.operationComplete(Bootstrap.java:166) ~[netty-transport-4.1.45.Final.jar!/:4.1.45.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListener0(DefaultPromise.java:577) ~[netty-common-4.1.45.Final.jar!/:4.1.45.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListenersNow(DefaultPromise.java:551) ~[netty-common-4.1.45.Final.jar!/:4.1.45.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListeners(DefaultPromise.java:490) ~[netty-common-4.1.45.Final.jar!/:4.1.45.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.setValue0(DefaultPromise.java:615) ~[netty-common-4.1.45.Final.jar!/:4.1.45.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.setSuccess0(DefaultPromise.java:604) ~[netty-common-4.1.45.Final.jar!/:4.1.45.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.trySuccess(DefaultPromise.java:104) ~[netty-common-4.1.45.Final.jar!/:4.1.45.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPromise.trySuccess(DefaultChannelPromise.java:84) ~[netty-transport-4.1.45.Final.jar!/:4.1.45.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.safeSetSuccess(AbstractChannel.java:984) ~[netty-transport-4.1.45.Final.jar!/:4.1.45.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.register0(AbstractChannel.java:504) ~[netty-transport-4.1.45.Final.jar!/:4.1.45.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.access$200(AbstractChannel.java:417) ~[netty-transport-4.1.45.Final.jar!/:4.1.45.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe$1.run(AbstractChannel.java:474) ~[netty-transport-4.1.45.Final.jar!/:4.1.45.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java:164) ~[netty-common-4.1.45.Final.jar!/:4.1.45.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:472) ~[netty-common-4.1.45.Final.jar!/:4.1.45.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.run(EpollEventLoop.java:384) ~[netty-transport-native-epoll-4.1.45.Final-linux-x86_64.jar!/:4.1.45.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:989) ~[netty-common-4.1.45.Final.jar!/:4.1.45.Final]
        at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74) ~[netty-common-4.1.45.Final.jar!/:4.1.45.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30) ~[netty-common-4.1.45.Final.jar!/:4.1.45.Final]
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: myidentityprovider.com: Temporary failure in name resolution
    at java.base/java.net.Inet4AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    Suppressed: reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblyException: 
Error has been observed at the following site(s):
    |_ checkpoint ⇢ Request to GET https://myidentityprovider.com/auth/realms/myrealm/protocol/openid-connect/certs [DefaultWebClient]
Stack trace:
        at java.base/java.net.Inet4AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Native Method) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.net.InetAddress$PlatformNameService.lookupAllHostAddr(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAddressesFromNameService(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.net.InetAddress$NameServiceAddresses.get(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getByName(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
        at io.netty.util.internal.SocketUtils$8.run(SocketUtils.java:148) ~[netty-common-4.1.45.Final.jar!/:4.1.45.Final]
        at io.netty.util.internal.SocketUtils$8.run(SocketUtils.java:145) ~[netty-common-4.1.45.Final.jar!/:4.1.45.Final]
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[na:na]
        at io.netty.util.internal.SocketUtils.addressByName(SocketUtils.java:145) ~[netty-common-4.1.45.Final.jar!/:4.1.45.Final]
        at io.netty.resolver.DefaultNameResolver.doResolve(DefaultNameResolver.java:43) ~[netty-resolver-4.1.45.Final.jar!/:4.1.45.Final]
        at io.netty.resolver.SimpleNameResolver.resolve(SimpleNameResolver.java:63) ~[netty-resolver-4.1.45.Final.jar!/:4.1.45.Final]
        at io.netty.resolver.SimpleNameResolver.resolve(SimpleNameResolver.java:55) ~[netty-resolver-4.1.45.Final.jar!/:4.1.45.Final]
        at io.netty.resolver.InetSocketAddressResolver.doResolve(InetSocketAddressResolver.java:57) ~[netty-resolver-4.1.45.Final.jar!/:4.1.45.Final]
        at io.netty.resolver.InetSocketAddressResolver.doResolve(InetSocketAddressResolver.java:32) ~[netty-resolver-4.1.45.Final.jar!/:4.1.45.Final]
        at io.netty.resolver.AbstractAddressResolver.resolve(AbstractAddressResolver.java:108) ~[netty-resolver-4.1.45.Final.jar!/:4.1.45.Final]
        at io.netty.bootstrap.Bootstrap.doResolveAndConnect0(Bootstrap.java:200) ~[netty-transport-4.1.45.Final.jar!/:4.1.45.Final]
        at io.netty.bootstrap.Bootstrap.access$000(Bootstrap.java:46) ~[netty-transport-4.1.45.Final.jar!/:4.1.45.Final]
        at io.netty.bootstrap.Bootstrap$1.operationComplete(Bootstrap.java:180) ~[netty-transport-4.1.45.Final.jar!/:4.1.45.Final]
        at io.netty.bootstrap.Bootstrap$1.operationComplete(Bootstrap.java:166) ~[netty-transport-4.1.45.Final.jar!/:4.1.45.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListener0(DefaultPromise.java:577) ~[netty-common-4.1.45.Final.jar!/:4.1.45.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListenersNow(DefaultPromise.java:551) ~[netty-common-4.1.45.Final.jar!/:4.1.45.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListeners(DefaultPromise.java:490) ~[netty-common-4.1.45.Final.jar!/:4.1.45.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.setValue0(DefaultPromise.java:615) ~[netty-common-4.1.45.Final.jar!/:4.1.45.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.setSuccess0(DefaultPromise.java:604) ~[netty-common-4.1.45.Final.jar!/:4.1.45.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.trySuccess(DefaultPromise.java:104) ~[netty-common-4.1.45.Final.jar!/:4.1.45.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPromise.trySuccess(DefaultChannelPromise.java:84) ~[netty-transport-4.1.45.Final.jar!/:4.1.45.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.safeSetSuccess(AbstractChannel.java:984) ~[netty-transport-4.1.45.Final.jar!/:4.1.45.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.register0(AbstractChannel.java:504) ~[netty-transport-4.1.45.Final.jar!/:4.1.45.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.access$200(AbstractChannel.java:417) ~[netty-transport-4.1.45.Final.jar!/:4.1.45.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe$1.run(AbstractChannel.java:474) ~[netty-transport-4.1.45.Final.jar!/:4.1.45.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java:164) ~[netty-common-4.1.45.Final.jar!/:4.1.45.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:472) ~[netty-common-4.1.45.Final.jar!/:4.1.45.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.run(EpollEventLoop.java:384) ~[netty-transport-native-epoll-4.1.45.Final-linux-x86_64.jar!/:4.1.45.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:989) ~[netty-common-4.1.45.Final.jar!/:4.1.45.Final]
        at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74) ~[netty-common-4.1.45.Final.jar!/:4.1.45.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30) ~[netty-common-4.
```

Comment: it looks like an issue in DNS name resolution. Am I right that you are running that code on some Pod? Does that Pod able to resolve `myidentityprovider.com` ?

Comment: This happens after putting the identity provider behind proxy with TLS. When this was http, it was fine. No idea what causes it.  I just tried with a new Ubuntu VM and standalone docker instance. Then I could reproduce the issue.   Also, the new VM is not able to resolve the DNS.  When I ping from vm   I get this  ping: myidentityprovider.com: Temporary failure in name resolution

Comment: and does it resolve any other host? would like to narrow down the root of the issue

Comment: I found the issue.  The DNS is mapped with wildcard.  I am not sure why the VMs are not able to resolve it. When I added the full subdomain directly. It started working.    Just to be clear  the domain mapping was *.mydomain.com.  so the VMs had trouble accessing identity.mydomain.com.   Now I added identity.mydomain.com then it started working. Thanks for your comments..

Comment: it would be good if you can post a solution as an answer. So the question wont be orphaned :)